# improve replace function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, replace, accent-sensitive

I am trying to perform this function in a cleaner way, could you give me a hand?

```
  function removeAccents(text) {

        var text = text.replace(/á/g, "a").replace(/é/g, "e").replace(/í/g, "i").replace(/ó/g, "o").replace(/ú/g, "u");

        return cadenaTexto;

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code already looks pretty clean to me, maybe you could put the replaces on separate lines, but it's easy to understand.

I'm not sure if the below code is any cleaner, but I'm just taking advantage of how you can pass a *replacerFunction* to [String.prototype.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

So that you can keep which characters you want to replace with which into a separate object and just pass them in.

```js
function removeAccents(text) {
  const replacements = { á: "a", é: "e", í: "i", ó: "o", ú: "u" };
  return text.replace(/[áéíóú]/g, match => replacements[match]);
}

console.log(removeAccents("áéíóú"));
```

Comment: If you just want to remove all accents, and not just those for a, e, i, o, and u (I'm not sure if there are any others) you can use ```text.normalize("NFD").replace(/\p{Diacritic}/gu, "")``` described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37511463/2746872)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: @Ryan White's Solution, using the match callback is by far the fastest solution being from 20% for shorter strings to more than 100% for longer ones, faster than both below solutions since it permits to avoid loops:

```js
const replacements = { à: 'a', è: 'e', ì: 'i', ò: 'o', ù: 'u' };

function removeAccents3(text) {
  const accs = Object.keys(replacements).join('')
  return text.replace(
    new RegExp(`[${accs}]`, 'gi'),
    (match) => replacements[match]
  );
}

console.log(removeAccents3('àèbgòè+àòètrysàùì')); //aebgoe+aoetrysaui
// Performance : 69059.40 ops/s
```

I propose a couple of approaches, they have similar performances, the replace through RegExp is more performant though, with short strings you don't notice it, but with longer ones you have a +20% of performance.

```js
const accents = [
  {
    val: 'à',
    repl: 'a',
  },
  {
    val: 'è',
    repl: 'e',
  },
  {
    val: 'ì',
    repl: 'i',
  },
  {
    val: 'ò',
    repl: 'o',
  },
  {
    val: 'ù',
    repl: 'u',
  },
];

const removeAccents = (text) => {
  for (const a of accents) text = text.replace(new RegExp(a.val, 'ig'), a.repl);
  return text;
};

console.log("First test:", removeAccents('àèbgòè+àòètrysàùì')); //aebgoe+aoetrysaui
// Performance : 46168.04 ops/s

// 2

const accents2 = {
  à: 'a',
  è: 'e',
  ì: 'i',
  ò: 'o',
  ù: 'u',
};
const removeAccents2 = (text) => text.split("").map(c => accents2[c] ? accents2[c] : c).join("")

console.log("Second test:", removeAccents2('àèbgòè+àòètrysàùì')); //aebgoe+aoetrysaui
// Performance : 45910.35 ops/s
```